# Webview thow Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IWebView6'

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, uwp

i have a problem with WebView/WebViewRenderer since i update to Xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2401

issue is that webview thow this exception

...
System.InvalidCastException
HResult=0x80004002
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IWebView6'.
Source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.add_SeparateProcessLost(TypedEventHandler`2 handler) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.NativeOrStaticEventRegistrationImpl.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2 addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2 addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WebViewRenderer.Connect(WebView webView) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e)
at LockerApp.UWP.Renderers.XWebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e) in C:\GitRepos\LockerApp\V2\LockerApp\LockerApp.UWP\Renderers\XWebViewRenderer.cs:line 27 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load() at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view) at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded(Object sender, ElementEventArgs e) at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnChildAdded(Element child)
at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnChildAdded(Element child)
at Xamarin.Forms.Layout`1.OnChildAdded(Element child) at Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.OnChildAdded(Element child) at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnInternalAdded(View view) at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item) at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
at Xamarin.Forms.ObservableWrapper`2.Add(TRestrict item) at Plugins.Popup.Layer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<AddItem>b__0() in C:\GitRepos\LockerApp\V2\Plugins.Popup\Layer.xaml.cs:line 53 at LockerApp.UWP.Plugins.TaskManagement.PlatformTaskDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0() in C:\GitRepos\LockerApp\V2\LockerApp\LockerApp.UWP\Plugins\TaskManagement\PlatformTaskDispatcher.cs:line 65
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
LockerApp.UWP.Renderers.XWebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView>) in XWebViewRenderer.cs
[External Code]
Plugins.Popup.Layer.AddItem.AnonymousMethod__0() in Layer.xaml.cs
LockerApp.UWP.Plugins.TaskManagement.PlatformTaskDispatcher.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() in PlatformTaskDispatcher.cs
...

Problem is 100% reproducible with following OS version
OS Name:Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise / OS Version:10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299)

FYI, my UWP project configuration is
target version : Windows 10, version 1003 (10.0 ; Build 18362)
Minimal vesion : Windows 10

any idea to solve that ?

Comment: I have done a sample to test the webview custom renderer with the Xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2401 on the Windows 11. It worked correctly. Can you try to debug to find which line cause the error?

Comment: Yes i confirm, there is no problem on windows 11.
Problem is only when i run my sample on Windows 10 16299 (1709)

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161125/xamarin-forms-uwp-platform-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-windows-ui-xaml-co/73162101#73162101).