# Xamarin.Forms : UWP platform : Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IWebView6'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, uwp, custom-renderer

- Xamarin.Forms version: 5.0.0.2401
- Windows version:

  - OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
  - OS Version: 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- Platform: UWP (Windows Universal Platform):
- Reproducibility: 100%
- Problem occurs each time using WebView with the following stacktrace:

  ```
    StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.add_SeparateProcessLost(TypedEventHandler`2 handler)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.NativeOrStaticEventRegistrationImpl.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2 addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2 addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WebViewRenderer.Connect(WebView webView)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e)
   at MyApp.UWP.Renderers.XWebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e) in MyApp.UWP\Renderers\XWebViewRenderer.cs:line 30
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetElement(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.SetupVisualElement(VisualElement view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded(Object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout`1.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnInternalAdded(View view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ObservableWrapper`2.Add(TRestrict item)
  ```

Do you have any idea about the root cause and solution to fix this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Xamarin.Forms : UWP platform : Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IWebView6'

The [problem](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/WebViewRenderer.cs#L125) should be related with the OS Version 16299, please check `IWebView6` interface, and it only contains one [SeparateProcessLost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.separateprocesslost?view=winrt-22621) event. but the SeparateProcess webview model avaiable start from Windows 10, version 1803 (introduced in 10.0.17134.0). So the workaround is update your OS to latest verison or reduce the xamarin form package version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Nico Zhu - MSFT.

Do you know any workaround which could be done by code instead of upgrading OS or reduce Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: Well, You may need to custom webviewrender and avoid use `SeparateProcessLost` event.

Comment: If you want to implement custom webviewrender, please don't inherit forms `WebViewRenderer`, you should make [ViewRenderer<>](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/WebViewRenderer.cs#L17) like forms made.

Comment: @MDIT Any updates for this thread ?

Comment: We're in-progress of trying old version of WebViewRenderer to see if the issue happens or not. If it still happens, we will try to inherit from ViewRenderer<> to customize the WebView.

Comment: Does ViewRenderer work  ?